# Optimization of Pig Script

Tags: java, shell, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have written a ‘Pig Script’ which is processing Sequence files given as input.
It is working fine but there is one problem mentioned below.

I have repetitive statements in my pig script,  as shown below:

```
Filtered_Data _1= FILTER BagName BY ($0 matches 'RegEx-1');
Filtered_Data_2 = FILTER BagName BY ($0 matches 'RegEx-2');
Filtered_Data_3 = FILTER BagName BY ($0 matches 'RegEx-3');
So on…
```

Question :
So is there any way by which I can have above statement written once and
then loop through all possible “RegEx” and substitute in Pig script.

For Example:

```
Filtered_Data _X  =   FILTER BagName BY ($0 matches 'RegEx');  ( have this statement once )
( loop through all possible RegEx and substitute value in the statement )
```

Right now I am calling Pig script from a shell script, so any way from shell script will be also be welcome or even Java wrapper...

Thanks in advance.
Happy Pigging!!!!

Comment: The fact that you're creating multiple bags, one for each filter, seems a little strange. It's not a common way to do things. Depending on what you're doing with these `Filtered_Data_X`, you might consider a different approach. But since you didn't show the later parts of the script, it's hard to know. Maybe give a little more context.

Comment: Sequence file which pig script is processing consist of many CSV files. With pig script i am trying to extract only selected files instead of all files. Once files are extracted i am storing each file individually in HDFS. So last statements will be a STORE statement for each selected CSV file.

Comment: I don't typically work on this aspect of the process, but I'd be more inclined to write a shell script or a Python script to do this reg ex and less inclined to do what you're suggesting in Pig itself.

Comment: If you read the question you can see I mentioned that i am trying to do same from shell script, but questions is how to loop through one pig statement from shell script and pass value of variables dynamically. Hope question is clear now.

Comment: @ChrisA.: Can you tell me the reason why you down voted this question. I posted it after trying many different things, did my research what else do you expect from a posted question. Can someone put light on this??

Comment: Actually, it wasn't my down vote. I thought it a reasonable question. The downvoter is not always the commenter.  But I stand my original comment that it depends on what you're doing with these bags afterwards. You should give more context if you want more help.

Comment: I am saving all the bags (Filtered_Data_1, Filtered_Data_2 and so on) separately into different directories in HDFS. Next step is creation of bunch of external tables in Greenplum on top of these extracted and stored bags. let me know if it is still not clear. I can share my pig script ( obviously in modified format ).